# Removing weights does not work flawlessly

Tags: weight-painting

I want to remove weights by painting 0% weight.

However, I'm having a hard time doing this.

[image]

Here is a video that shows how I desperately try to paint an area black.
I have to try it again and again until finally *something* happens:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrBMwwcDY4A

These are my brush settings:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: @moonboots That is what I want, but it does not really work. In the video you see how I desperately go over the blue areas again and again, and they still stay blue.

Comment: yes sorry, my bad, it looks like tmighty is right, but I'd like to understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The falloff seems to be the important factor here:

[image]

Once I sat it to the bridge-like preset, it worked fine.

Comment: it looks like you're right, so what was the problem?

Comment: @moonboots The falloff shape was "wrong" for my project / geometry, I would say.

Comment: mmh Ok, I thought Mix with a Weight of 0 equaled Subtract with a Weight of 1, so maybe to always make sure you're deleting, switch to Subtract

Comment: @moonboots Where is Subtract to be found?

Comment: in your 3D view > panel the right panel with N > Tool > Brush > Blend > Subtract

Comment: @moonboots Thank you, but that is not different than painting with 0 weight. The thing really seems to be the fall-off.